# How can I limit the access to a database in google cloud import interface?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL server running MySQL that is used by low technical knowledge users to import csv's to a MySQL database. They use the Import function built into GC SQL. However, there are several databases and I would like to limit access to a database to each user.

Here is the menu that I refer to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Ftq.png

I already tried assigning a IAM Role with less access but everything excep SQL Admin greyes out the Import option. SQL Admin gives complete access to even delete the instance so its definitely not an option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To manage access at the database level (anything internal to Cloud SQL), you need to use MySQL Access Control. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-control.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Indeed, IAM role allow you to control access to GCP component. Here, your requirements is to administrate user that access to specific database schema, which is the role of DBA.

The only solution is to build something on top of Google API for limiting/controlling access.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old issue, but you can limit access via. [IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) that target specific resource names (or even better, using [Tags](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/tags/tags-creating-and-managing)). This way, you can grant specific permissions that only apply to specific resources. You might need to create a custom Role that only has these permissions (such as update, connect, etc.) as the default Cloud SQL ones are a bit broad.

Unfortunately, this doesn't fully solve the issue around provisioning the resources as you will need broader permissions to create the resource, but once the tags are applied, you can then manage it with greater granularity.

The other option is to have a really granular GCP hierarchy and apply permissions at different project/group levels, but obviously this becomes a bit of a maintenance nightmare.